# How to run sql query with NodeJs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, bots, messenger

I'm trying to making a messenger bot, and I have a problem with these codes

```
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
    event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i]
    sender = event.sender.id
    if (event.message && event.message.text) {
        text = event.message.text
    var mysql      = require('mysql');  
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({  
    host     : 'localhost',  
    user     : 'root',  
    password : '',  
    database : 'dictionary'  
    });  
    connection.connect();  

    connection.query("select * from `en_ku` WHERE `english` LIKE ('%{"+text+"}%')", function(err, rows, fields)   
    {  
    if (err) throw err;  
    if (rows[0] != null){
        text = rows[0];  
    }
    else {
        text = "sorry not have any result for: "+ text;
    }
    });  

        connection.end();  
        if (text === 'hi') {
            sendGenericMessage(sender)
            continue
        }
        sendTextMessage(sender, text.substring(0, 200))
    }
    if (event.postback) {
        text = JSON.stringify(event.postback)
        sendTextMessage(sender, "Postback received: "+text.substring(0, 200), token)
        continue
    }
}
res.sendStatus(200) 
})
```

if I remove the codes from `var mysql      = require('mysql');` to `connection.end();` the code will work and the bot works like a parrot!
anyone can tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: Ah maaan, don't require library and create database connection inside a loop, take it outside, connection.end() also must be outside the loop

Comment: thank you for your help, I tried your way but also thats not work :/ ,